# Rearrange the sentence in a specific order

Tags: sentence, word-order, business-language, sentence-patterns, sentence-starts

Sentence: Developers from 10+ countries are using our service.

I want to rearrange this sentence so that it starts with **"10+ countries"**. But keep the meaning of the sentence the same.

I want to achieve this pattern (a number followed by a short phrase) ↓↓↓
[image: what to achieve]

But I cannot find a way to start with **"10+"**
I want to rearrange the specified sentence such that it starts with a number(which in this case is 10+) and then there will be a phrase. It need not be a complete sentence. But the meaning should be preserved

Any suggestion gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In 10+ countries, developers are using our service.

Comment: @PeterShor I have edited the post. Please check.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should not start a sentence with a numeral.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I have edited the question. I want to rearrange the specified sentence such that it starts with a number(which is 10+) and then there will be a phrase. It need not be a complete sentence. But the meaning should be preserved

Comment: 10+ countries where developers are using our service...

Comment: @Justin It is just what I needed. But, can it be shortened a little more. You can add this as an answer

Comment: @DronBhattacharya: 10+ countries where developers use our service... This is the shortest it can get.

Comment: @Justin It is great. It will work fine. Thanks

Comment: _10+ countries' developers are using our services_ is one possibility.

Comment: >10 works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *10+ countries where developers use our service*

or

> *10+ countries with developers using our service*

---

Complete sentences, for reference:

[There are] 10+ countries where developers [make] use [of] our service.

[There are] 10+ countries with developers using our service.